# Make button animation not go over drawable background

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-button

[Top button: Not pressed, bottom button pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2v1bj.png)

How do make the "default" block animation on button click on android to fit the drawable background that is set? The drawable background gives the buttons rounded corners.

Edit: ripple.xml works, but lays over button text.

Button:

```
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="test123"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/settings"
        android:foreground="@drawable/ripple"
        />
```

Drawable setting_button

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

Ripple.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
                android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/setting_button" />
</ripple>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this lies in the special mask layer of the RippleDrawable. You specify the mask layer via the android:id value set to @android:id/mask.
https://proandroiddev.com/rippling-rounding-and-android-pies-d5db5f4c2fc1
http://michaelevans.org/blog/2015/05/07/android-ripples-with-rounded-corners/

```
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/setting_button"
    android:foreground="@drawable/ripple"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:text="test123"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@color/settings"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

And remove `<item android:drawable="@drawable/setting_button" />` from the ripple drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
<item android:id="@android:id/mask">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#000000" />
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
            android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: I did not quite understand how to implement this fix. Michals solutions seems easiest, but  proandroiddev says this will break the pressed state on Oreo. Im making for API 23 and above.

Comment: Added ripple.xml with item android:drawable= drawable used to make rounded corners. No effect.

Comment: Create new resource file for ripple drawable as decribed in Michals post. Then reference this drawable in foreground of your button instead of selectableItemBackgroundBorderless

Comment: My bad, looks like its working now. But now the solid color from the rounded button style lays over the text.

Comment: Solid color should be in background. The ripple foreground should be pale, so I would not expect it covering the text. Not sure now. Pls post the code

Comment: Thought i already tested your solution with removing drawable from ripple. But it works now! thanks